# RIDE can't find firefox geckodriver while running screen-test

Tags: selenium-firefoxdriver, robotframework-ide

I have a 'hello world' test to open a browser using firefox.
The test runs fine on the commandline ($ robot hai_world.robot).
But it fails when I run the test in RIDE. It reports:
WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
Does RIDE have its own PATH-setting?
It runs on ubuntu 20.04 in RIDE v2.0b1 on Python 3.8.10

Comment: If you start RIDE from that same commandline, would it find geckodriver?
Where is geckodriver (in a usual PATH location)? Paste here `which geckodriver`

Comment: 'which geckodriver' gave: /home/hobijn/.local/share/WebDriverManager/bin/geckodriver. I started RIDE from the same commandline. The RIDE can open the browser. So the starting location makes the difference.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: To react on the Community-bot: RIDE is started by a desktop-shortcut and robot direct on a commandline in a console opened on the robot project directory. That results in a different start-path and thus a different path to search for the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Because your geckodriver is in a location defined in PATH only for your user, RIDE does not know of this when started from the shortcut.

I see (at least) two options to fix this:

- Create a link to geckodriver in a global PATH location, for example:

  `sudo ln -s /home/hobijn/.local/share/WebDriverManager/bin/geckodriver /usr/local/bin/geckodriver`
- Modify the launcher script of RIDE to have PATH updated:

  `export PATH=$PATH:/home/hobijn/.local/share/WebDriverManager/bin ; python3 -m robotide.__init__ $*`

Comment: Thanks. Starting RIDE on a commandline has an other advantage: browsing of a file starts at the projects root and no longer at the root of the filesystem. As most files are in the project it safes a lot of clicking.